# Error/warning when automatically loading pacman in .Rprofile

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to load packages automatically upon startup. I have lifted the code directly from the pacman site. My `.Rprofile` file looks like this:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load("plyr","dplyr","ggplot2")
```

However, when I load the project, I get this output:

```
Loading required package: pacman
Error: could not find function "install.packages"
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘pacman’
[Workspace loaded from C:/Users/agood.../.RData]
```

What am I doing wrong? This error occurs whether or not the packages are loaded with or without quotes.

Comment: Try adding `library(utils)` before that line.

Comment: I think that worked, as the packages are loaded. But I still get the warning message.

Comment: @Adam_G: to get rid of the warnings, look at the `library(quietly, verbose, warn.conflict)` options, and fail that, use `suppressWarnings()`